# DBEAVER not showing SQL Server clustered index in DDSL

Tags: sql-server, ddl, dbeaver

I am having the following issue in DBEAVER 21.2.4 and SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.4178.1).

Whenever I see the DDL from SQL Server (`Script Table > Create as`), it displays the whole constraints:

```sql
...
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Emp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [EmpID] ASC
    )
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100, 
              OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

While DBEAVER displays only

```sql
...
    CONSTRAINT PK_Emp PRIMARY KEY (EmpID)
```

and no data in constraints.

Not clustered. not Pad_index, nothing.

[image: No Constraints]

Is this a bug in Dbeaver, or am I missing something?

Comment: It's probably just a "feature" of DBeaver; the scripted results are generated by the tool in question from querying the system tables, SSMS just gives you a lot more detail inc defaults. If you want the best SQL Server experience, use SSMS.

Comment: hi @stu, yes I get your point ( of using SSMS ) , my goal was to focus my energies in only one tool. I am basically recreating a pipeline where I added 2 new columns. and I was copiying the DDL from beaver.  but I guess the initial phase of my DEV will be spent collecting DDLs directly in SSMS. thank for the help though

Comment: Consider using SMO objects or Powershell for such things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Emp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmpID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CONSTRAINT PK_Emp PRIMARY KEY (EmpID)
```

are identical, because CLUSTERED is the default for PRIMARY KEY constraints, [PRIMARY] is the default filegroup, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS defaults to ON, etc.

SSMS always explicitly scripts each option, and apparantely dbbeaver omits opions that it thinks are using the default values.

Comment: Oh that is something that I was not aware of / forgot. ( I havent worked with DDLS in almost 8 years ) . Thanks for the hint :)